# Generalising relation between hypotenuse and other side of right angled triangle in arbitrary vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, triangles, inner-products, orthogonality

I was working on my Linear algebra homework and I felt I needed to prove this statement (which might not be true), but is at least true for $\mathbb{R}^2$ from a right angled triangle.

Given a inner product space $V$ with derived norm $|| \cdot || = \sqrt{\langle\cdot ,\cdot\rangle}$. Let $a,b,c \in V$. Show that
$$
c-a~\bot~b-a \Rightarrow ||c-b|| \geq ||c-a||
$$

Can someone help me proving this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If you have an argument for $\mathbb{R}^2$, can you phrase it in terms of the norm, inner product etc on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 2):

Using the theorem in our book that states,
Given an inner product space $V$ with derived norm $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle = \sqrt{||\cdot||}$ we have for $u,v \in V$, if $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$ then
$$
||u + v||^2 = ||u||^2 + ||v||^2
$$
Choosing $u = a-b$ and $v=c-a$ we have $u + v = c - b$ using the theorem we get
$$
||c-b||^2 = ||a-b||^2 + ||c-a||^2
$$
since $||a-b||$ is positive we have
$$
||c-b||^2 \geq ||c-a||^2 \iff ||c-b|| \geq ||c-a||
$$